# Angular issue when trying to link service to controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, apache-tiles

i'm trying to develop a web app using Angularjs, I could implement the ui-router framework succesfully, and the template and controller are loaded correctly, but then, the controller calls a service and is there when I'm getting an error that i cannot get rid off (`https: //docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=HomeServiceProvider%20%3C-%20HomeService%20%3C-%20HomeController`). I'm importing the js files in the following order:

1-service
2-controller 
3-main app

Also here you have an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E95qc.png) (the code is after clicking on the state) with the html code. The js files are the following:

home-app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module("home", ['ui.router', 'home.controllers'])

    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $stateProvider
                .state('introduccion', {
                    url : "/",
                    templateUrl : "resources/js/home/views/introduccion.html",
                    controller : "HomeController"
                })
}]);
```

home-service.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('home.services',['ngResource'])

    .factory('HomeService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

        return {

            prueba: function() {
                return $http.get('http://localhost:8081/home/prueba').then(

                    function(response){
                        return response.data;
                    }, 

                    function(errResponse){
                        console.error('Error while prueba');
                        return $q.reject(errResponse);
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }]);
```

home-controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module("home.controllers", [])

    .controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'HomeService', function($scope, HomeService) {
              var self = this;
              self.text = null;

              self.prueba = function(){
                  HomeService.prueba().then(



                   function(data) {
                        self.text = data;
                   },

                   function(errResponse){
                        console.error('Error while Prueba');
                   }
              );
          };
}]);
```

All help is welcome!!! thanks

**EDIT** i changed the home-app passing the home.service as suggested, and also i tried putting it on the home-controller, but in both cases i'm getting the same error: Failed to instantiate module home due to:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=h...)
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:6:412
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:40:134
at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:7:355)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:39:222)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:39:391
at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:7:355)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:39:222)
at bb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:43:246)
at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:21:19
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwDez.png)

I also created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txominsirera/0s2d2zyr/

**EDIT** i found something interesting, i replaced the service js with a dummy service, with no ngResource dependecy, and i got no errors with it!!

Comment: write the controller as `angular.module("home.controllers", ['home.services'])` . You need to inject the service module in controller module.

Comment: doing that throws another error... https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: i edited the text, maybe it can help you something, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download [angular-resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) file in your app to inject `ngResource` as dependency in `home.services` module. It's needed to use `$resource` as dependency in angular factory/service. As I am seeing you have not used `$resource` in `home.services` module, you can remove `ngResource` as your module dependency.

And then, write the controller as `angular.module("home.controllers", ['home.services'])`. You need to inject the service module in controller module.

See this working [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UUnloNZkLNNdpmg3ICJu?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

in home-app.js add module home.services like:

```
    angular.module("home", ['ui.router','home.controllers','home.services'])
```

instead of :

```
angular.module("home", ['ui.router', 'home.controllers'])
```